# vb .net null condition

Tags: .net, datetime, null

this is my code -

```
            Dim provider As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
            Dim a1 As DateTime = Nothing
            insexp = DateTime.ParseExact(date1.SelectedValue, "MMMM yyyy", provider)
            If a1.Month = Today.Month AndAlso a1.Year = Today.Year Then
                a1 = Today.Date
            End If
```

this will work only if date1.selectedvalue is not null, but will crash if it is null.
how do i give if condition to run this only if not null?
thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
If date1.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing Then
    ...
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim provider As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        Dim a1 As DateTime = Nothing
        If not String.IsNullOrEmpty(date1.SelectedValue) Then         
    insexp = DateTime.ParseExact(date1.SelectedValue, "MMMM yyyy", provider)
         End If
    If a1.Month = Today.Month AndAlso a1.Year = Today.Year Then
        a1 = Today.Date
    End If
```